# Running a command on all matching files in a directory

Tags: unix, awk

What's the simplest way for running a command like this

```
ffmpeg -i MVI_NNNN.MOV -sameq -ar 22050 MVI_NNNN.mp4
```

on all `.MOV` files in a directory? The input filename `MVI_NNNN.MOV` would be something like `MVI_0849.MOV` and the output should preserve the file number, so `MVI_0849.mp4`.

Answer (score 3):

Try `for...loop`:

```
for i in *.MOV
do
    ffmpeg -i "$i" -sameq -ar 22050 "${i%.MOV}.mp4"
done
```

---

- `${i%.MOV}.mp4` will remove `.MOV`, append `.mp4`
- `"..."`(double quotation marks) are needed if filenames contain white-spaces

Comment: This will break on filenames with spaces unless you quote properly.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`GNU parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) running one `ffmpeg` instance per CPU core to speed things up:

```
$ parallel ffmpeg -i {} -sameq -ar 22050 {.}.mp4 ::: *.MOV
```

See [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html) for tweaks.